# Mongoose save() function error object for duplicate keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I have using mongoose promise to catch error when user try to register new user and email. Here is the code:

**user.service.js**

```
function create(userParams) {
    var user      = new User(userParams);
    return user.save();
}
```

and on my API router, here is the code to call the function:

**user.controller.js**

```
function register(req, res) {
    var user = {
        uname    : req.body.uname, 
        email    : req.body.email, 
        password : req.body.password
    }
    userService.create(user)
        .then(function(){
             res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'User Created!' });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.status(400).send(err); 
        })
}
```

It's working properly when I run the function and the data stored on mongoDB. The one that I want to know is, I've added `unique` property on both uname and email, so when I am trying to create duplicated value on either one, it will generate an error. This is the body error that has been 'catched'

```
{
   "code":11000,
   "index":0,
   "errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: flash-card.users index: name_1 dup key: { : null }",
   "op":{/*Contain all info that want to be registered*/}
}
```

I tried to create duplicated value but it was showing the same error above without indicate which property that have duplicate value. Any other idea/approach to get specified on which property that got error/duplicate value?

Comment: Looks like you are getting null as name. And that already exists in DB. Thats why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clues are there:

```
collection: flash-card.users
index: name_1
dup key: { : null }
```

It looks like your schema once has a property called `name` (inferred from the index name) that was marked unique.

I think that at some point, you renamed that property (possibly to `uname`), but the unique index on `name` *does not get automatically removed* when you do that.

Instead, for every new document, MongoDB will assume that your document has a `name` property with value `null` (this behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/), starting with *"By contrast, ..."*), and once the first document has been inserted, any subsequent document will trigger the E11000 error.

To solve this problem, you need to remove the `name_1` index (which you have to do from the Mongo shell, or something like RoboMongo/Robo 3T perhaps).

Comment: thank you for the clue! I've remove the index of uname and it shows the correct duplicate key.